# EF related entities not showing when empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a context that links two DbSets. They are linked by an CustID. If the CustID does not exist in the related table then the query does not return the entry at all. For example, I have a CustID shown in one grid and the order details of the CustID in another grid. If the CustID does not have an orders the CustID columns does not show up in the first grid.

Here I have tried to use the DefaultIfEmpty method on the include but that is not working. I'm not sure how to show if there are no related entities.

```
var q = from b in _myContext.Customers
            .Where(b => b.Name == "XYZ").Include("OrderDetails")
            select b;
```

Comment: What you explained is an inner join in relational database terms. If you where to use a join instead it would filter as desired. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#inner-join

Comment: How do I use the join instead of the include? This is an error:

Comment: var q = from b in _myContext.Customers
            .Where(b => b.Name == "XYZ").Join("OrderDetails")
            select b;

Comment: just to be clear, are you trying to return customers with no orders? Or are you trying to return only customers that have orders?

Comment: I am trying to include customers that have no orders. Its a one to many relationship. I was hoping I could just simply change the .Include to a .Join somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join to ensure customer records returned are linked to an order. If a customer has no matching orders, that customer will not appear in the results.

```
from customer in myContext.Customers
join order in myContext.OrderDetails on order.CustID equals customer.CustID
select customer;
```

Use a left outer join if you intend on returning customer records even when not linked to any orders.

```
from customer in myContext.Customers
join order in myContext.OrderDetails on order.CustID equals customer.CustID into customerGroup
from record in customerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new Customer())
select customer;
```

> In a left outer join, all the elements in the left source sequence are
>   returned, even if no matching elements are in the right sequence. To
>   perform a left outer join in LINQ, use the DefaultIfEmpty method in
>   combination with a group join to specify a default right-side element
>   to produce if a left-side element has no matches. You can use null as
>   the default value for any reference type, or you can specify a
>   user-defined default type.

Lastly, you are mixing Linq and Lambda in your example. As a best practice, you may want to use one or the other; in case you prefer, here is the lambda equivalent for the inner join example:

```
myContext.Customers
         .Join(myContext.OrderDetails, 
               customer => customer.CustID, 
               order => order.CustID, 
               (customer, order) => customer);
```

HTH

Comment: Could you show me the equivalent lambda expression for the left join as well. I will give this a try.

Comment: I'm trying to add DefaultIfEmpty(new Customer()) but it does not recognize the Defaultempty for my class.

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` is part of Linq so make sure you have a reference to it: `using System.Linq`

Comment: When I run the above join query then do a .ToList() I'm getting the following error: The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Comment: @HALO try using `customerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()`. If you still get the same error, please include your code in the post.

Comment: var q = from customer in _context.Customers
    join order in _context.OrderDetails on customer.Id equals order.Id into customerGroup
    from record in customerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new Customer())
    select customer;

    q.ToList();

Comment: Actually I added this line of code to enable logging of the SQL query : myContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);  This showed that my query with the .Include was actually doing the left join by default for Entity Framework. Here is a useful link that illustrates this: https://melontech.com/blog/2015/left-joins-with-entity-framework